# java regex "^" and "\A" difference

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to regex. I try to research it.

I am reading following article:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

snippet from article:

```
^   Matches beginning of line.
```

and

```
\A  Beginning of entire string
```

I don't understand the difference. Can you clarify this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Difference is apparent when you use `MULTILINE` switch where `^` is matched at start of every line but `\A` is still matched only once at start of very first line.